# Fetch API with query only available with full words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to make react movie app with API.
I tried to fetch API with query.
This is working only when it matches with certain characters.
For example, if I put 'jur' in searchbar, there is no result, but if I put 'jurassic', and then the results show up.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Movie from "../components/Movie"

function Home() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")
  const getMovies = async () => {
    const json = await (
      await fetch(
        `https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=year&query_term=${searchTerm}`
      )
    ).json()
    setMovies(json.data.movies)
    if (movies !== []) setLoading(false)
  }
  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies()
  }, [searchTerm])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        onChange={inputHandler}
        value={searchTerm}
        placeholder=""
      ></input>
      {loading || movies == null ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {searchTerm}
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <Movie
              key={movie.id}
              id={movie.id}
              coverImg={movie.medium_cover_image}
              title={movie.title}
              year={movie.year}
              rating={movie.rating}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Your issue is originated from server's API. But you posted frontend code.

Comment: @LikiCrus Oh, I didn't know that it was an issue from API.. I thought that there would be a way to write query to search including some words. Thanks for the comment, by the way.